# Circle with text in Tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am beginner webdeveloper.
I have small problem with Tailwind CSS. I need this: https://ibb.co/KL8cDR2

This is my code:

```
<div class="w-1/2 h-10 rounded-full bg-gray-400" style="background-color:red">404</div>
```

but it's not working :( How can I make it?
Please help me

Comment: Does this is your expectation? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/OJXXQWB

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```html
 <div class="font-bold text-gray-700 rounded-full bg-white flex items-center justify-center font-mono" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; font-size: 170px;">404</div>
```

This should do the job. Make sure to add a custom class which defines height and width of the circle as well as the font-size and remove `font-mono` from classes and add your wanted font.

Answer (score 9):

**The position absolute way:**

```
<div class="rounded-full border-2 flex p-3 relative">
    <div class="absolute top-5 left-8">
        4
     </div>
</div>
```

In tailwind.config.js extend inset

```
theme: {
  inset: {
     '5': '5px',
     '8': '8px'
   }
}
```

**The flex way:**

```
 <div class="w-20 h-20 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center">
       <p>404</p>
 </div>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="w-20 h-20 rounded-full border-2 border-black flex justify-center items-center">
       <p>404</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: adding a line height make things a lot better. You may try it with the property 'leading' https://tailwindcss.com/docs/line-height

Answer (score 3):

you can use width and height in this way by pixel or something

```
<div class="w-[200px] h-[200px] bg-red rounded-full flex 
 justify-center items-center">
   <p>404</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rounded` class with different options.

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="m-3 flex h-20 w-20 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-blue-600">
    <p>Circle</p>
  </div>

  <div class="m-3 flex h-20 w-20 items-center justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 text-center">
    <p>Rounded Square</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]